# Why is object member value changing between 2 getter calls

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am getting unexpected value in second getter call which looks wrong to me, any specific reason for this happening?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {

public:
    int &t;
    Test (int x):t(x) { }
    int getT() { return t; }
};

int main() {
    int x = 20;
    Test t1(x);
    cout << t1.getT() << " ";
    cout << t1.getT() << endl;

        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The member `t` references the locally scoped parameter `x`, *not* the `x` defined in `main`.  So you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. right but shouldn't it give random value in first call itself ? as that scope is till constructor call ?

Comment: Undefined Behavior -- you can't expect anything.

Comment: @HemantKr Undefined Behavior is just that, undefined. You can get any output, or no output at all at, you can't predict or rely on it in any way.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour, in general case, is not a random number generator.

Comment: Can you tell the difference between a random 20 and a non-random 20?

Comment: @molbdnilo second call is not always generating same number, but first call is always giving 20, that can't be random 20 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your code results in undefined behavior.

The constructor of `Test` does not take a reference to an int but a copy, and due to `int x` only being a temporary copy which is not guaranteed to live until your second function call you will end up with undefined behavior.

You would have to change your constructor to the following to make the code work properly:

```cpp
Test(int& x) : t(x) {}
```

Now the reference you're working with in `Test` will be the same `x` as defined in `main`

Comment: How is it living till first function call always

Comment: @HemantKr It is not. The first call is also an UB, it is just a coincidence that you see your value from x.